# Find text in a table array excel

Tags: excel

below is an extract of a large table (2017 IDs by 35 cases)

I want a formula which will look for a Case reference e.g. P0093 and return the first ID it finds (column A).

So for example, given 'P0094', the formula will result in '1'.

I expect the answer is something to do with an array formula, which are a bit of a blindspot for me.

Thanks in advance.

```
ID  Case 1  Case 2  Case 3  Case 4  Case 5
1   P0001   P0092   P0093   P0094   
2   P0016   P0150   P0419   P0420   
3   P0018   P0189   P0421   P0422   
4   P0004   P0095   P0096   P0097   
5   P0005   P0104   P0105       
6   P0021   P0068   P0069       
7   P0007   P0098   P0099   P0100   
8   P0008   P0101   P0102   P0103   
9   P0009   P0062   P0233   P0234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (line break added for readability)

```
= IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,(MMULT((A1:E10="P0094")+0,
  TRANSPOSE((COLUMN(A1:E10)>0)+0))>0)+0,0)),"no match")
```

Just change both instances of `E10` in the formula above to however large your actual data table is. (Assuming 2017 ID's and 35 cases, I would probably change `E10` to `AJ2018` but I don't know for sure.)

Also note this is an array formula, so you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the keyboard after typing this formula rather than just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks Imaginary, lovely stuff. I don't understand what it's doing, but it gives the expected results.

Comment: `MMULT`, `INDEX`, `TRANSPOSE`, `MATCH`, and `SUMPRODUCT` are in my opinion some of the most useful Excel functions that, when used together in an array formula, can accomplish mostly anything. I recommend researching these individual functions to learn about what their inputs/outputs are and look at some other Excel questions on SO to see them in action so that you can learn how to use them and understand these types of formulas when you see them.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely spend some time getting to know these better.

Answer (score 1):

## non CSE alternative

See the picture for cell reference layout.  Use the following formula in I13:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$10,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$E$10)/($B$2:$E$10=$I$12),1)),"not found")
```

Aggregate performs array like operations without actually being an array.

The concept is to find the row where the value you are looking for is true and all other rows become an error. It starts by making the denominator return TRUE or False.  Because the TRUE or FALSE is sent through a math operation Excel converts the TRUE to 1 and FALSE to 0.  Since all values divided by 0 become an error, only rows where the denominator are true are going to be kept.  The reason for this is the 6 in the aggregate function which tells aggregate to ignore all errors.  15 in aggregate tell aggregate to sort the results from smallest to largest.  Finally the ,1) tells aggregate to return the first value in the list.   Once that is known, INDEX takes over.  Index returns the row entry in the range A1:A10 that is passed from aggregate.  If the range had been A2:A10, then I would have to subtract row(A2)-1 to get the starting entry number in the list instead of the row number.

An important thing to note.  Even though this is not an array, AGGREGATE performs array like calculations.  As such full column references should be avoided within the AGGREGATE function to avoided wasted calculations on blank cells.

[image: POC]

Comment: Nice call using the `IFERROR` to check for no matches. I will add that to my formula also.